# Tomcat, enabling HTTPS to a partcular context path

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https

We are deploying 2 wars in tomcat 7. eg:   contexta.war  and contextb.war.

We need to enable SSL on contexta.war, but not on contextb.war.

I have gone through http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html.  But I didn't get how to do for a particular war.

There is an alternative by using Apache HTTP server.  But, it is not we are looking for.  We would like to configure only through tomcat. Is it possible?

Thanks

Please help.

-Prakash